# jQuery animate does not work well on FireFox?

Tags: jquery

I have the below codes:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQuery animate()</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #circle {
            height: 200px;
            width: 200px;
            border-radius: 100px;
            background-color: red;
        }   
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="circle"></div>

    <script>
        $("#circle").click(function() {
            $(this).animate({
                width: "300px",
                height: "300px",
                borderRadius: "150px",
                marginLeft: "100px",
                marginTop: "100px"
            }, 1700);
        });
    </script>   
</body>
</html>
```

It works well in Chrome where the circle is moving nicely downwards but not in Firefox (v43.0.4), IE and Edge.

What am I missing here? I am new to jQuery, just want to understand if there is something I have done wrong here.

Thank you.

Comment: install firebug and check for 'jquery' error...

Comment: i have installed and can't see any errors...

Comment: Jquery `animate()` is specifically slow. You should go for CSS animation or transition. Otherwise, this could improve performance too: http://julian.com/research/velocity/

Comment: thanks @A.Wolff, it's useful, for a beginner like me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change the border-radius in your css:

```
#circle {
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    border-radius:100%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

In this way circle will be always a circle.

```
$(this).animate({
    width:"300px",
    height:"300px",
    marginLeft:"100px",
    marginTop:"100px"
 }, 1700);
```

Now in jQuery you don't need to use `borderRadius`.

Answer (score 2):

For best performance (and easier-to-maintain code), whenever possible use CSS animations instead of animating in javascript:

```js
$('#circle').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

```css
#circle {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: 1.7s;
}

#circle.clicked {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 150px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="circle">
```